# Sequelize query by date ignoring time

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to use sequelize to `findAll` my rows that has been created on a specific date.

Imagine I want to find all my books where `createdAt` match `2022-07-01`. By default, Sequelize `createdAt` row is `datetime` and not `date`.

I would like to avoid doing a query with "between 2022-07-01 00:00 and 2022-07-01 23:59" but instead doing a match directly on the column. Which is SQL would be : `SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE DATE(createdAt) = "2022-08-23"`

My current sequelize doesn't return anything, cause it is still comparing `datetime` instead of only the date : `where: { createdAt: "2022-08-23" },`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, "%Y-%m-%d")`

There's some references on W3schools https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp